# Generating unique view ids

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table in mysql database and I would like to be able to generate a unique string so that user can input the string that will run the appropriate query and display the result.

Ex)

```
id | text         | view_code <--this would be randomly generated
1  | testing      | fsj2343lfs
2  | another_test | fsdflj2dff
```

There would be a text box on a page that will take **view_code** as input. If text input matches one of the view_codes in the table, the appropriate record will be displayed to the user.

EDIT: The idea is that I would give user #1 view_code of 'fsj2343lfs' and this will return only record '1 | text' and display it on the webpage. This is to ensure that that user only sees that record, and does not have access to any other records in the database.

Is this a good way of going about this? Is there another way that would work better? Thanks!

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: I'm wondering if the above is a good way of generating codes that I could give to users that, when entered, will pull the appropriate record and display it to the user. For example, I would give user #1 the id of 'fsj2343lfs' and when that user enters that id on a webpage, they will see record '1 | testing' that will be pulled from the database. The table will contain a bunch of records but user #1 only needs to see record with id 1 and no other records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *correct* way to do what you're trying to do would be to have the user log in upon their initial visit to your site, and then store their `username` and `password` in `$_SESSION` variables. Then, when you go to compare the unique ID entered by the user, you would ask your database to verify the unique ID for the user who's username and passwords matches the valeus stored in your `SESSION`.

Comment: I have auto-incrementing field in table (id column). Would i just give user the auto-incrementing id of the record they are interested in? That doesn't sound secure as any other user can enter a number and potentially see another record in the database.

Comment: There is nothing insecure about giving a user an auto generated number. Most systems do this to specify rows when generating HTML tables, etc.

Comment: So if I have text box on a page that prompts for auto-generated number, that's OK? There's no need to generate a random string to give the user instead? I feel like another user can enter a random low number (i.e. 2) into the text box and have access to the record they shouldn't be seeing.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully it's more clear but not sure how to explain it better.

Comment: would I store username and password as part of the record? For example:
id | text | user | pass?